# Reactjs: How to access state of child component.from a method in parent component that depends on state of child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

I need to access a method `handleCancelEdit()` defined in parent component. But, the matter here is that every child component will have its own `cancelEdit` state. Now, what is happening is, if I call `handleCancelEdit()` from one child component, every other of the same child components is taking the state and updating themselves(the method is not completely defined yet). That's why, I have defined the `cancelEdit` state in the child component, thinking that it belongs to this child component only.

Now, how do I make the `handleCancelEdit()` method make changes to the only child component which called it?

The parent:

```
function Parent() {
    const handleCancelEdit = () => {
        setCancelEdit(!cancelEdit);  // defined in child component
        setEdit(!edit);       // defined in child component
        ...
    };
    return (
    <div>
        <ChildComponent
            fieldName={"Email"}
            value={email}
            inputType={"text"}
            placeHolder={"Enter email"}
            name={"email"}
            on_change={(e)=>setEmail(e.target.value)}
            on_click={handleUserEmail}
         />
         <ChildComponent
             fieldName={"About"}
             value={about}
             inputType={"text"}
             placeHolder={"Enter some details about yourself"}
             name={"about"}
             on_change={(e)=>setAbout(e.target.value)}
             on_click={handleUserAbout}
         />
    </div>
    );
}
```

Child component:

```
function ChildComponent({fieldName, value, inputType, placeHolder, name, on_change, on_click}) {
    const [ edit, setEdit ] = useState(false);
    const [ cancelEdit, setCancelEdit ] = useState(false)
    const isEdit = edit;
    return (
        <p>{fieldName}: {value === ''? (
            <span>
                <input type={inputType} placeholder={placeHolder}
                    name={name}  onChange={on_change}
                />
                <button type="submit" onClick={on_click}>Add</button>
            </span>
            ) : ( !isEdit ? (<span> {value} <button onClick={e=>setEdit(!edit)}>Edit</button></span>) :
            (<span>
                <input type={inputType} value={value}
                        name={name}  onChange={on_change}
                />
                <button type="submit" onClick={on_click}>Save</button>
                <button type="submit" onClick={handleCancelEdit}>Cancel</button>
            </span>)                            
            )}
        </p>
    );
};
```

I hope it could make it understandable that one child component should not make others to update. Now, how do I do it in this scenario?

**EDIT**

After making changes according to Linda Paiste:
[image: gif of error]

The input field in the child component is not working even though the `onChange` in both parent and child is correct!

Comment: Why can't `handleCancelEdit` just live inside the child component?

Comment: Are you trying to pass state up from the child to the parent? If so, you need to pass a reference to a function in the parent as a prop to the child. The child can then call that function however you want and can distinguish itself from other child components. 

Another alternative would be to use a state management library like redux.

Comment: @Denno I think then I need to use `ref` as I saw in other questions but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: @Ezra am I not doing the same, i.e. *passing a reference in the parent as a prop to the child* in my code? If not, how do I do that?

Comment: Where does the parent call `handleCancelEdit`?  Is it trying to cancel all children or just specific ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always more logical to pass state and data down rather than up.  If the `Parent` needs to interact with the `edit` state then that state should live in the parent.  Of course we want independent `edit` states for each child, so the parent can't just have one `boolean`.  It needs a `boolean` for each child.  I recommend an `object` keyed by the `name` property of the field.

In `ChildComponent`, we move `isEdit` and `setEdit` to props. `handleCancelEdit` is just `() => setEdit(false)` (does it also need to clear the state set by `onChange`?).

```
function ChildComponent({fieldName, value, inputType, placeHolder, name, onChange, onSubmit, isEdit, setEdit}) {
    return (
        <p>{fieldName}: {value === ''? (
            <span>
                <input type={inputType} placeholder={placeHolder}
                    name={name}  onChange={onChange}
                />
                <button type="submit" onClick={onSubmit}>Add</button>
            </span>
            ) : ( !isEdit ? (<span> {value} <button onClick={() =>setEdit(true)}>Edit</button></span>) :
            (<span>
                <input type={inputType} value={value}
                        name={name}  onChange={onChange}
                />
                <button type="submit" onClick={onSubmit}>Save</button>
                <button type="submit" onClick={() => setEdit(false)}>Cancel</button>
            </span>)                            
            )}
        </p>
    );
};
```

In `Parent`, we need to store those `isEdit` states and also create a `setEdit` function for each field.

```
function Parent() {
  const [isEditFields, setIsEditFields] = useState({});

  const handleSetEdit = (name, isEdit) => {
    setIsEditFields((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [name]: isEdit
    }));
  };

  /* ... */

  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComponent
        fieldName={"Email"}
        value={email}
        inputType={"text"}
        placeHolder={"Enter email"}
        name={"email"}
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        onSubmit={handleUserEmail}
        isEdit={isEditFields.email}
        setEdit={(isEdit) => handleSetEdit("email", isEdit)}
      />
      <ChildComponent
        fieldName={"About"}
        value={about}
        inputType={"text"}
        placeHolder={"Enter some details about yourself"}
        name={"about"}
        onChange={(e) => setAbout(e.target.value)}
        onSubmit={handleUserAbout}
        isEdit={isEditFields.about}
        setEdit={(isEdit) => handleSetEdit("about", isEdit)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

You can clean up a lot of repeated code by storing the `values` as a single state rather than individual `useState` hooks.  Now 5 of the props can be generated automatically just from the `name`.

```
function Parent() {
  const [isEditFields, setIsEditFields] = useState({});

  const [values, setValues] = useState({
      about: '',
      email: ''
  });

  const getProps = (name) => ({
      name,
      value: values[name],
      onChange: (e) => setValues(prev => ({
          ...prev,
          [name]: e.target.value
      })),
      isEdit: isEditFields[name],
      setEdit: (isEdit) => setIsEditFields(prev => ({
          ...prev,
          [name]: isEdit
      }))
  });

  const handleUserEmail = console.log // placeholder
  const handleUserAbout = console.log // placeholder

  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComponent
        fieldName={"Email"}
        inputType={"text"}
        placeHolder={"Enter email"}
        onSubmit={handleUserEmail}
        {...getProps("email")}
      />
      <ChildComponent
        fieldName={"About"}
        inputType={"text"}
        placeHolder={"Enter some details about yourself"}
        onSubmit={handleUserAbout}
        {...getProps("about")}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: "(does it also need to clear the state set by onChange)"? Yes, when Cancel is clicked, whatever edit was done must revert back to the last saved text.

Comment: Is this the preferred approach over `forwardRef`, since `forwardRef` is to be used in rear occasions?

Comment: Yes this is the preferred approach.  There is a docs section that I often link to on [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: Hey, I have implemented the parent and child as you have mentioned. When I'm clicking edit, the value is changing to a text input but it's not editable. The `onChange` is not working somewhere!

Comment: @Strange_air Can you post a demo of the issue?  I don't have enough information to know why it's not working.

Comment: I had accidentally edited your answer. This GIF in my edited answer explains the problem. When I am clicking on Edit, the input field is appearing but the text is not editable.

Comment: Found out the issue. the `value` prop in child component should be `value={data}` instead of `value={myData.data}`.

Comment: But, still one issue is there. If I write some text and then click `Cancel`, then instead of restoring the previous value, the input field is leaving behind the new edited value!

Comment: Post a CodeSandbox and I can fix it.

Comment: This is the Codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/late-sun-skxkt?file=/src/App.js

Comment: My first thought was to store all initial/saved values in a separate state in the Parent.  But now I think that the Child should store the text input state and it should update the Parent on clicking "Save" instead of on every change.  It kind of depends on the desired behavior.  Can you "Cancel" after you have already "Saved" to revert to a previous value?  Is it one "Save"/"Cancel" for the whole form or one for each field?  I think I got it: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-cancelable-edit-lq4p4?file=/src/EditProfile.js

Comment: You're right. Each field is edited as inline forms, for every child it is. So in this case we're passing down component specific prop right?

Comment: Yes everything that you pass down is specific to that field.